# Slow SeekBar performance on Android

Tags: android, performance, seekbar

I'm trying to hook up a basic audio player. The audio side is done, but I'm using a SeekBar as a track scrubber and I'm having trouble with performance.

The SeekBar is from an XML layout, and I'm using fairly basic code to update it:

```
updateTask = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {

        int elapsed = 0;
        if (player != null) {
            elapsed = player.getElapsedTime(); // Seconds
        }
        trackSeekbar.setProgress(elapsed);
        updateHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }

};

updateHandler.postDelayed(updateTask, 1000);
```

This code is taking between 20%–50% CPU on a Nexus 10! It makes other parts of my app are very choppy so it has to be faster.

I have already taken out some things in the layout to try and reduce layout redraws (I was displaying the elapsed time in a text box but gave up because it was just too slow), but I do need a basic scrubber. When I take out the call to `setProgress()` CPU drops to 1%. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: does seek bar use any no std resources (progress drawable, thumb drawable)?

Comment: Yes — I have a custom thumb and progress drawable, but when I remove them it doesn't change the CPU use.

Comment: hmm really strange, try to Log.d in your run method to check if its not called too often

Comment: Yes, just tested the `run()` call and it's being called once a second. I also noticed if the value given to `setProgress()` doesn't change, CPU doesn't spike. So it must be something to do with layout?

Comment: seems so, maybe its a good time for a traceview?

Comment: or try to play with http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html and see what happens to seek bar parent containers

Comment: Got it! I had a high resolution background image on my app, and removing it restored performance to <5% CPU across the board. Thanks for your help.

Comment: well i didnt help much,  it was you who found it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the poor performance was a high resolution transparent PNG in the background. When I removed it, all the various performance issues disappeared.

On the Nexus 10, the image was 2560x1440 which is its native resolution. Seemingly Android is not able to cope with full resolution background images.

Comment: Could be an overdraw-related problem. Recommended reading: http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/01/android-performance-case-study/

Comment: Yes — this was the case.